# How to change logstash create ES index timezone?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

logstash.conf:

```
    elasticsearch{
      hosts => ["172.31.29.xxx:9200"]
      index => "redis-%{+YYYYMMdd}"
    }
```

I used YYYYMMdd to define index ,I want to change the index timezone,How can I do it?
thx

Comment: Elasticsearch and Logstash uses time in UTC, if you use a date format like `%{+YYYYMMdd}` to create your index, it will get the date and time from the field `@timestamp` which is in UTC, you can't change that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [logstash "date" filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) to change log event timezone.

Here is an example of a `logstash.conf` file I have put together to show you how and where the date filter goes:

```
input { 
    file {
        ...
        type => "typeName"
    }
}

filter {
    if [type] == "typeName" {
        grok {
            match => {"message" => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:event_timestamp}..."}
        }
    }
    date {
        match => [ "event_timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
        timezone => "Etc/GMT"
        locale => "en"
    }
}

output {
    if [type] == "typeName" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
            index => "indexName"
        }
    }
}
```

you can look at the [available timezone values here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html).